# How to run dockerized tests in Gitlab CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

My app depends on many external binaries to be in $PATH at **runtime** (in the example I use curl and wget).

My idea was to create a `base` docker stage where all dependencies are installed - and then extend on it for the  `production` and the `test` stage:

```
FROM alpine:latest as base
WORKDIR /app
# install runtime dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add curl wget

FROM base as development
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN make dev-dependencies
CMD make dev-server

FROM development as test
WORKDIR /app
CMD make test

FROM alpine:latest as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN make dev-dependencies
RUN make build-prod

FROM base as production
COPY --from builder /app/dist/app /app
CMD ./app
```

Because the tests also need some services (mysql in the example) I planned to use docker-compose to run them:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:latest"

  develop:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
  
  test:
    profiles:
      - test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: test
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

if I am correct I would be able to start the tests using `docker-compose --profile test up` and  build the production image with `docker build -f Dockerfile -t app .`. Both would use the same dependencies of the `base`.

I am very unsure whether this will work as I have planned and whether the tests can run in the Gitlab CI in the end.

- Is my approach correct / good practice?
- Can I run the tests in the Gitlab CI in the same way?

I already have a working Dockerfile with prod and test stages. But I stopped before creating the docker-compose file because of my mentioned concerns.

I also thought about running the tests in a single docker stage without docker-compose. While researching I found this Gitlab issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22801 so my conclusion was that this would cause problems.

Comment: What are the tests doing exactly ? Are these integrations tests that are run against your application (i.e the develop container), or are these just unit tests that also need a MySQL service ?

Comment: @ABWassim Just unit tests

Comment: And these unit tests need the MySQL service ? I'm just trying to figure out everything :)

Comment: @ABWassim yes they need 3 services. I picked MySQL as an example

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments your approach is almost good. You can use [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) rather than running a docker-compose inside your GitLab CI job. Services allow you to run extra containers next to the job's container (for example, a MySQL database). If the services need to reach each other, make sure to use the [FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/feature-flags.html#available-feature-flags) feature flag.

However, unit tests aren't meant to use external dependencies. Still, I would recommend the following process in your case :

- A first job that would install the binaries, build the code and run the unit tests with the help of the Services.
- A second job that would build and push the production image. You would then only need the production part in your Dockerfile.

One improvement would be that you're not testing the production image, aka. the image that will be sent into production, which is why having unit tests against the code and integration tests against the production image would be a plus.

Also, one good pattern would be to "drag" the same Docker image(s) across the pipeline to ensure integrity. One way to achieve this would be to rewrite the Dockerfile like so :

```
FROM alpine:latest as base
WORKDIR /app
# install runtime dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add curl wget

FROM base as development
COPY . .
RUN make dev-dependencies
EXPOSE 3000

FROM alpine:latest as production
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN make dev-dependencies
RUN make build-prod

FROM base as production
COPY --from builder /app/dist/app /app
CMD ./app
```

In your CI, first build the `development` and the `production` image. Then run tests using the `development` image as your job's `image`. If tests succeed, then do whatever you have to do with the production image (for example retag it with a final version).

Finally, update you docker compose to use the same `development` target. You would just need to fill in the `make dev-server` command or the `make test`.

Comment: How would I run the tests and develop locally?

Comment: You can keep your docker-compose for local tests, and use services within GitLab CI.

Comment: Your solution would not reuse my Dockerfile setup and I would need to manage dependencies twice. Once in the Gutlab CI and once in the Dockerfile. How can I make sure that the dependencies do not differ?

Comment: I've just updated my answer to include this. Indeed, this would be another improvement, I just wanted to go step by step :)

Comment: Ok that means it is possible to build an Docker image and run it inside Gitlabs CI runner Docker, right? So the only think I have to manage twice is the configuration of the Services

Comment: Yes it's called "Docker in docker". Here is the GitLab documentation : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html You can skip the whole GitLab runner configuration if you're gonna use the public GitLab platform. You would also need to push the image to a docker registry so subsequent jobs could pull it using the `image` attribute of a GitLab CI job.

Comment: Why is it so damn complicate to run Docker env from Dockerfiles... I really do Not Like the Gutlab CI.. is there No better setup? :(

Comment: That's the only way to do it properly in GitLab CI.